# SQL where clause with session variables

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

I have created my session variables in form.php file as

```
<?php
session_start();   
include_once("connect.php");

$n=$_POST['name'];
$p=$_POST['password'];
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE `userName`='$n' AND `password`='$p'");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==1){
    $_SESSION['user']=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

userName is a field in table member. Now in another PHP file I want to execute this code

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

$q2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE userName='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']['userName'])."'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($q2);
```

}

Where from another table (table2) I select all the fields which have the logged users username.  (userName is a field in table2 as well)
But in order to check if this works I typed 
`echo $row['userName']`

```
$q2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lecturer WHERE userName='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']['userName'])."'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($q2);
```

Can someone point out where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Make sure that $sql is having data before putting it into session variable.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ` even before session_start(). But still nothing happens

Comment: what about `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`? and is `session_start();` present in all files using sessions? you have session arrays here too, two of them. That may be failing.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  In formdata.php I changed as `$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE `userName`='$n' AND `password`='$p'" or die(mysql_error()));

if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==1){
 $_SESSION['user']=mysql_fetch_array($sql);`  Now I get an error as ` mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource `.But earlier it logged the user with no issues

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have used session_start() at every page which uses session variables

Comment: is your connection indeed `mysql_` based and not `mysqli_`, or PDO? that error is usually associated with that message.

Comment: @Fred-ii- My connection is `<?php

$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("d1") or die("couldn't connect to db");

?>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didn't make any change to my previous code.But now it works. When I type `echo $row["userName"];` it works. Thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome, glad to know it was resolved, *cheers*